# Oracle IO Performance & Optimize design database

Tags: database, performance, oracle, database-design

I'm being optimize my Oracle Database.
I confusing about IO Performance between write concurrent 10 request to a Table and write concurrent 10 request to 10 table

and if i have 10 type data can store in 1 table --> which way bring the best performance insert data between 1 or 10 table

anybody know about it ?

Comment: are you asking if there is a difference between inserting 10 rows into one table or inserting 1 row into 10 different tables ?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? Do you currently have a performance problem, or are you considering different schema designs and trying to anticipate problems? It would generally not be a good approach to design your database schema based on considerations like this -- the design should almost certainly be normalised, or you will face other issues.

Answer (score 2):

Performance tuning is a large topic, and questions can't really by answered with so little information to begin with. But I'll try to provide some basic pointers.

If I got it right, you are mainly concerned with insert performance into what is currently a single table.

The first step should be to find out what is actually limiting your performance. Let's consider some scenarios:

- disk I/O: Disks are slow. So get the fastest disks you can get. This might well mean SSDs. Put them in a RAID that is tuned for performance, "striping" is the key word as far as I know. Of course the SSDs will fail, as your HDs do so you want to plan for that. HDs are also faster when they aren't completely full (never really checked that). Partitioned tables might help as well (see below). But most of the time we can reduce the I/O load which is way more efficient then more and faster hardware ...
- contention on locks (of primary keys for example).
  Partitioned tables and indexes might be a solution. A partitioned table is logically one table (you can select it and write to it just like a normal table), but internally the data gets spread across multiple tables. A partitioned index is similar but an index. This might help, because an index underlying a unique key get locked when a new value gets added, so two sessions can't insert the same value. If the values are spread between n indexes, this might reduce the contention on such locks. Also partitions can be spread over different tablespaces/disks, so you have less waiting time for your physical stuff.
- time to very constraints: If you have constraints on the table they need time to do their job. If you do batch insert, you should consider deferred constraints, they only get checked on commit time instead of on every insert. If you are careful with your application you can even disable them and enable them afterwards without checking them. This is fast, but of course you have to be really really sure the constraints actually hold. of course you should make sure your constraints have all the indexes they need to perform good.
- talking about batch inserts. If you are doing those you might want to look into direct load: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58227/ch_dlins.htm (I think this is the Oracle 8 version, I'm sure there is an updated documentation somewhere)

To wrap it up. Without knowing where exactly your performance problem is, there is no way one can tell how to fix it. So find out where your problem is, then come back with with a more precise question.

Comment: Many thanks Jens for answer my question, those tip very helpful But my problem is: fire 1000 request into one table has partition ( 10 partition) and fire 1000 request into 10 table ,which way is the best perfomance ?

Comment: As I tried to scetch above, this depends on: type of request (insert, select, delete / where clause, data) constraints and indexes on your tables as well as the hardware you have available (are all partitions on the same disk)